# GridView Event RowCreated it happens after rendereing of controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need change the value for a Label inside a GridView programmatically.

I user this code but does not work. I am not able to Find the Control.

- My questions is _RowCreated event fire BEFORE the Controls are rendered?
- If yes, which Event shall I use?

Thanks

```
       protected void uxListAuthorsDisplayer_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            int myRowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
            //Label myLabel = (Label)e.Row[myRowIndex].FindControl("uxUserIdDisplayer");
            if (myRowIndex >= 0)
            {
                //e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Ciao";
                Label myLabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("uxUserIdDisplayer");
                myLabel.Text = "TEST";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're searching for a cell with index "RowIndex" in your row.

```
protected void uxListAuthorsDisplayer_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Skip the header and footer rows
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label myLabel = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("uxUserIdDisplayer");
    }
}
```

I prefer to use the RowDataBound event, since that one occurs when the data has been bound to the row, so that you can access the data via DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "a data item")

Answer (score 1):

The [GridView.RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) event is appropriate. Maybe you should check if it is not a header row for example, case when indeed there is no control to find:

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    Label myLabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("uxUserIdDisplayer");
    myLabel.Text = "TEST";
}
```